# Imports in pancakeswap periphery do not exist

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance

I'm looking for someone to give me a basic understanding and direction regarding pancakeswap forking. I cloned pancake-swap's periphery [repository](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery) from github and in its contracts it imports "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IPancakeFactory.sol" for example. When I install uniswap a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPEUt58_574&t=205s) on forking pancakeswap but it is very vague and doesn't seem to help me. Any help will be highly appreciated. Also why are there 2 router files instead of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also following this guy's Uniswap tutorial and ran into the same problem.  Check out what some of the other pancakeswap clones did - for example ApeSwap (https://github.com/ApeSwapFinance/apeswap-swap-periphery/tree/master/contracts)

They created their own IApePair and IApeFactory in interfaces of the periphery folder and just import those files.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Can you also guide me what should are these two parameters IBEP20 _lp and address _wbnb in BnbStaking.sol of pancakeswap? https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-farm/blob/master/contracts/BnbStaking.sol

Comment: What I do know is that the I in IBEP20 stands for interface. An interface that defines what the behavior of ab object should be.
I'm afraid that's all I know sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/issues/4).

The fix suggested in the bug is to edit package.json doing something like this:

```
yarn add @uniswap/v2-core@git://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-core.git
```